# Unity Crouching w/ State Machine Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have set up a state machine for my player in Unity. I have a Crouch state and an Idle state. I want the player to crouch when I hit the crouch button when it is in Idle state and go back to Idle when I hit the crouch button again while I am crouching. The problem (I think) is that when I hit the crouch button it goes into the crouch state but then immediately goes back into Idle state. I have another script that is detecting each state and doing stuff based on what state the player is in at the moment. What is the best way to solve this issue? Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum PlayerState
{
    Idle,
    Walking,
    Sprinting,
    CrouchedIdle,
    CrouchedWalking
};

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerState playerState;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        playerState = PlayerState.Idle;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlayerState();
    }

    //Detects input from player and switches player state accordingly
    void UpdatePlayerState()
    {
        if (playerState == PlayerState.Idle)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 ||
                Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Walking;
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 && Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Sprinting;
            }
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.CrouchedIdle;
            }
        }
        if (playerState == PlayerState.Walking)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 && Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Sprinting;
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 && Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0)
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Idle;
            }
        }
        if (playerState == PlayerState.Sprinting)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 && Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0)
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Idle;
            }
            if(!Input.GetButton("Sprint") || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Walking;
            }
        }
        if(playerState == PlayerState.CrouchedIdle)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 ||
                Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.CrouchedWalking;
            }
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Idle; //If I comment this line out I can crouch normally but can't stand up, however if I leave this line in I can't crouch at all.
            }
            if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 && Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Sprinting;
            }
        }
        if(playerState == PlayerState.CrouchedWalking)
        {
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Walking;
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 && Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.Sprinting;
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 && Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0)
            {
                playerState = PlayerState.CrouchedIdle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a series of `if` condition that can all be true in the same frame.

Let's see what happen in one frame:

- The `if (playerState == PlayerState.Idle)` condition is verified.
- Within this `if` statement, the `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))` condition is verified, so your player enters the `PlayerState.CrouchedIdle` state.
- The `if (playerState == PlayerState.Walking)` condition is not verified, so let's skip to the next one.
- The `if (playerState == PlayerState.Sprinting)` condition is not verified, so let's skip to the next one.
- The `if(playerState == PlayerState.CrouchedIdle)` condition is verified.
- Within this `if` statement, the `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))` condition is verified, so your player enters the `PlayerState.Idle` state again!
- Finally, the `if(playerState == PlayerState.CrouchedWalking)` condition is not verified.

One solution could be to use a series of `else if` instead of `if`, this way you would only have one change of state per frame (since only one of the condition would be considered per frame).

I would also suggest looking at examples of state machine implemented in C#, in order to avoid this kind of pitfall.